# How to handle a BUS in Verilog with multiple drivers

Tags: verilog, processor, xilinx, bus

I'm trying to connect multiple modules in verilog sharing a common "BUS" of size 16bits. I'm having trouble connecting multiple inputs(drivers) to the BUS. When I attach more then one driver, I get an error within Xilinx.

> Signal BUS in unit {Top_Module_Name} is connected to following multiple drivers:

The code I have for the modules are

```
input         en;
output [15:0] BUS;
reg    [15:0] data;

if (en) begin BUS = data;
else BUS = 16'dZ;
```

In the top module I have something similar to

```
module1(en1,wBUS);
module2(en2,wBUS);
module3(en3,wBUS);
```

I have a controller controlling enables with 1 hot encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `BUS` output is not a `reg`, but a `wire`. To use `BUS` in a `IF` statement (inside a combinational `always` of course) `BUS` has to be defined as `reg`.

Something like this:

```
module something (input en, 
                  output reg [15:0] bus
                 ); 
  reg [15:0] data = 16'hABCD;  // some value;

  always @* begin
    if (en)
      bus = data;
    else
      bus = 16'hZZZZ;
  end
endmodule
```

If `bus` is going to be a wire...

```
module something (input en, 
                  output [15:0] bus
                 ); 
  reg [15:0] data = 16'hABCD;  // some value;
  assign bus = (en)? data : 16'hZZZZ;
endmodule
```